# Custom control style only applies to contextmenu when it appears for the 2nd time

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, styles, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a context menu without the iconbar on the left.

The way im doing this is through a custom style that applies to all the ContextMenus and MenuItems in my window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            ...
            ...
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Background="White"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="-20,0,-40,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I am then spawning the ContextMenu on a button in my window:

```
                        <Button Content="Add"
                            Margin="5"
                            Width="90"
                            ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom">
                        <Button.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ModifierOptions}"/>
                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                    </Button>
```

The problem is that the first time the context menu appears, it lacks the styles, so it still has the side column

If i right click the button again after that, the style is applied correctly and no side column is present.
Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: I removed MergedDictionaries from your example, and than it worked fine. Not sure why, yet...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could move your style to separate `ResourceDictionary`. It works in my case.